# Far from being of purely theoretical interest

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> The sun is surrounded by a powerful magnetic field, which, **far from being of purely theoretical interest**, has profound effect on life on Earth in the form of its effect on radio communications.

Can you please explain the sentence in simple form, specially the bold part?

Answer (score 1):

If something is "of purely theoretical interest", it has no consequences in everyday life.

An example is the fact that there are black holes in the universe... it's very interesting, but it won't change our lives.

Now, if something is "far from" that, it means that it is no longer purely theoretical. It has implications for our lives. In particular, the solar magnetic field affects radio communications on earth, including how well communications satellites work.